# MVC3 Modal Dialog Based on Session Variable

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I am developing an MVC app in which data is year specific. So, I need to make sure the working year is set before any data is queried. I asked this question before and received the response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364432/mvc3-global-variable). This works just fine to redirect the users to another page. However, this is problematic because the session expiring (I do not want it to be a no expire session). So, if there is inactivity for the session to expire and the user is in the middle of an operation, I do not want the page to be reset because of a redirect to another page to select the year.

After that long introduction (apologies, I wanted to make it clear what I was needing), I ask, is it possible to create a modal dialog if the session is null?

For example:

```
if (Session["Year"] != null)
{
    ...
}
else
{
    modal dialog to set year and go on our merry way...
}
```

I looked at examples for jquery UI, but it does not seem to address my particular conundrum.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, here is the jQuery UI component for dialogs. You have to place it in your view though, so you'll have to pass whatever session value you have to the view so that you can do a logical test there.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

UPDATE:

You can create a view that will hold your dialog box. Next you will override the OnActionExecuted Controller action which gets executed on every request. In this action you will do your session check.

Then you will use ViewBag to pass a value to your master/layout view. In that view just do a logical check for the ViewBag value, and show the dialog box appropriately.

```
if (Session["Year"] != null)
{
    ...
}
else
{
@Html.Raw(@"
<script type='text/javascript'>
   $(document).ready(function(){ 
      $('#dialogID').dialog('open'); //I am not sure if this is proper way to open it
   });
</script>")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I reviewed jQueryUI already and did indeed see the option for dialogs. My question was more focused on how to implement the dialog and use that with a session variable. I am currently using an ActionFilter to do a redirect - I do not want to redirect to another page, nor do I want to place the same code in every view.

Comment: Updated the answer. Instead of doing every view, just put it once in your layout.

Comment: How do I get the dialog to load? I see in tutorials how to do it when clicking a button, but how do I use a razor block to execute e.g. @if (Session["Year"] == null) { load jquery dialog }? Still fairly new at this, btw, so simplicity is helpful :)

Comment: Updated the answer. You just use $(document).ready() to open it automatically when page is loaded

Comment: It is working, but there is one issue. The partial view is a form (used to select from available defined years from the db). The dialog loads, but as soon as I select a year I am redirected to the view. So, my partial view is located at SelectYear/Index. That is what loads in the dialog. After year is selected, I am redirected to SelectYear/Index. Is there a way to prevent the form from redirecting?

Comment: You have to pass the path that you are currently at with the form and then just redirect to the same path. You could also post the form with Ajax, and then just either close the dialog or refresh the page.

Comment: Since the form is located at SelectYear/Index, when the form is loaded in the jQuery dialog, the path always shows SelectYear/Index (I am using Request.Url.PathAndQuery)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in javascript with a mixture of server side assigning to javascript variables. For eg.

```
<script>
    $(function(){ 
        var showDiag = @(ViewData["Year"] ?? false);
        if(showDiag){
            //code to show
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I incorporated this into above solution. Works good with slight mod (using session, not viewdata). Thanks.